# The MailSpool service is not available

Tags: coldfusion

I started getting errors:

```
coldfusion.server.ServiceFactory$ServiceNotAvailableException: The MailSpool service is not available. 
This exception is usually caused by service startup failure.
Check your server configuration.
```

It started happening after installing newest windows updates. I cannot even access CF administrator.

```
Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise

ColdFusion 9.0.1
```

There is a log after last reboot: [pastie.org/9456023](http://pastie.org/9456023)

Comment: Looking into logs I found those errors:http://pastie.org/9456181 when I checked those files on the server, both are empty.

Comment: Two files got corrupted: 
\lib\neo-cron.xml
\lib\neo-mail.xml
Restored them from the backup, restarted server and worked.

Comment: You should post that as an answer to your question and accept it. It is okay to do that here and makes it easier for future visitors to find. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 1):

Two files got corrupted: \lib\neo-cron.xml \lib\neo-mail.xml Restored them from the backup, restarted server and worked